# Rails AddAttributeToModel won't display newly added record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I've just started learning RoR and i'm really stuck. I've created a new app and i'm trying to add a phone number field to a previously created form (Tickets). I've created the database, added a migration script using :

```
rails generate migration AddPhoneToTickets phone:string
```

plus migrated it using :

```
rake db:migrate
```

Last, i've added the field to all the relevant html.erb files.
When I add a new record to the App, the phone attribute is showed and when I fill it in and click "Update" I receive the message : "Ticket was successfully updated."
Unfortunately the phone number isn't saved in the DB and isn't displayed in the listings.

Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 2):

Should be a problem of strong parameters: check in your TicketsController if your ticket_params method looks like this:

```
def tickets_params
   params.require(:ticket).permit(whatever_other_params, :phone)
end
```

YOu can also check if in your server log, when saving it is saying Unpermitted param.

Have a look here:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately I don't have any params mentioned anywhere in the controller code. I'm not sure this is the case.

Comment: if you're using Rails 4 you sure have something like that  in your controllers (Rails 4 is based on strong parameters), otherwise it shouldn't be possible for you tu update any of the params. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails 4 look for ticket_params method in the controller and add :phone to .permit where the other attributes are listed